# Proving the asymptotic behavior of the prime counting function (Prop 2.1 in Ch.7 Princeton Lectures in Analysis-Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory

This is taken from Complex Analysis by Elias M. Stein and Rami Shakarchi.
$\psi(x) \text{ is Tchebychev’s ψ-function defined by}$
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{p^m\leq x} \text{log }$$
the sum is taken over the integers of the form $p^m$ and $p^m\leq x$ where $p$ is prime and $m\in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0} $.
And$$\pi(x)=\text{number of primes less than or equal to }x$$
[image]

[image]

[image]

I do not understand how the last inequality is derived.
Dividing through x and rearranging give
$$\frac{\psi(x)}{x}\geq\alpha\pi(x)\frac{\text{log}(x)}{x}-\alpha\pi(x^\alpha)\frac{\text{log}(x)}{x}$$
Do I then take limsup of both sides? but then how does the right hand side "transform" into that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the text, $\pi(x^{\alpha})\le x^\alpha$, which gives $-\alpha\pi(x^\alpha)\frac{\log x}{x}\ge -\alpha x^{\alpha-1}\log x$ (the inequality is reversed because of the minus sign). Upon taking $\limsup_{x\to\infty}$ of this expression you get $0$, because $\alpha-1<0$.